# What is the maximum likelihood estimation for a binomial distribution with zero successes in the data?

Tags: binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Say a random variable `X` is distributed as `binomial(10, theta)`.

In the data, out of 10 trials, there are 0 successes (i.e. 10 failures).

How to calculate MLE for theta for such data?

How does MLE change when it is given that `0 < theta < 1` vs `0 <= theta <= 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The MLE for Bernoulli distribution is computed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275380/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-bernoulli-distribution).

In your case it leads to $\theta=0$. And MLE doesn’t change when you change from closed to open interval for $\theta$.